# Autosizing vertical line in Obj-C on OSX

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I have this window :

[image]

And when I resize it, it becomes like this :

[image]

In XCode Builder, I have this config for the vertical line :

[image]

My question is : How can I autosize the vertical line so that it moves along the tableview.

(The right empty space has a custom view. It's not really empty.)

**EDIT**
Here is the table view autosizing

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In autoresizing masks system, it is not possible to have the line to stay at fixed distance from right edge of the table view during resize, unless the table view right edge is also pinned to container's right edge. So you need to place both table and the line into another view (Custom View) and configure flags like this:

```
Table View:    |====| <====> |=====|
Vertical Line:  ----   ----  |=====|
```

The best you can achieve without an extra container is to disable all horizontal flags for the line, but then the distance between it and the table will variate as the window resizes.

Alternatively, consider using AutoLayout, this is just one of many reasons it was created.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the table view's springs are wrong. The line itself appears to be moving fine, based on the screenshot.

Comment: Edited my question with the autosizing of the tableview